# If a PPA application crashes Unity on exit, do I file a bug against the app or Unity?

Tags: unity, ppa, bug-reporting

Every time I close Darktable 1.0.4 in Ubuntu 12.04, Unity crashes, and then restarts.

My question is, since Darktable has been installed via PPA, would I report the bug to the Unity team or the Application team?

I understand this may be too localised, but am struggling to find an answer to this one.

Comment: Is it Darktable that makes it crash at all? could be something else.

Comment: It seems to be. It's the only application that crashes Unity when I close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Note:* In general, PPA applications are not supported by Ubuntu/Canonical in any official way. (They are *personal* package archives, after all :-)

In your case, since it appears that only one particular PPA application is causing this problem, I highly recommend filing a bug with them first. After following their instructions for troubleshooting (if any), if the developers recommend filing a bug against Unity, certainly do so.

If you had more than a few different applications crashing Unity, you could consider filing a bug directly against it, but not in this situation.